# Best Environment For Windows Mobile 5 Development

Tags: windows-mobile, development-environment

I got my Pocket PC(HP iPaq Hx2490b) and now I want to know which is the best environment to develop for it, things like IDE, Windows version, language, .Net framework version...? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your favorite version of Windows with Visual Studio 2008 should work fine. Visual Studio will install all the .NET frameworks you need.

For language, you'll likely want to use C#.

Have a look at the Getting Started guides [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx) for some places to start.

Comment: Thanks very much, very nice explained and a good link and this is good because I was learning C# :) and I already have the license of Visual Studio 2008 and using Windows Vista.